# django import with csvimport.py fails when trying to create a reference to a foreign key

Tags: python, django

current django project is a mini shop thing.

im trying to create the concept of having products which could have a foreign key of a Brand and a Category. however the import im using is this one http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/788/

and it fails when trying to create the object on the foreign key field. it puts the error message 
    ValueError: Cannot assign "'Brand.dubkorps'": "Product.brand1" must be a "Brand" instance.

I get that im not putting the right value in the csv file for the foreign key i'm trying to reference, my question is, how do i work out what the value is for this particular foreign key?

love to hear from anyone who has done something similar with csvimport.

Answer (score 0):

if in the import file you have the ID of an existing brand you have two choiches:

```
brand = Brand.objects.get(pk= csv_val)
product.brand = brand
```

or

```
Product.brand_id = csv_val
```

hope it helps

Comment: Ive moved on a little now
    python csvimport.py --csv dubkorps.csv --mappings  1=partno,2=brand1(Brand|ID),3=category1(Category|ID)

gives an error message of
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
    django.db.utils.IntegrityError: shop_product.brand1_id may not be NULL

i think the issue is that im trying to populate the brand1 field with the number that brand.id contains in the FK. 
so i've tried the same thing only with the Brand name filed in the csv...

i.e.
    python csvimport.py --csv dubkorps.csv --mappings "1=partno 2=brand1(Brand|name) 
the same error message

Comment: i cant get the hang of formatting.

python csvimport.py --csv dubkorps.csv --mappings 1=partno,2=brand1(Brand|id),3=category1(Category|id)....

this still errors but with a new error.
that is, 

django.db.utils.IntegrityError: shop_product.brand1_id may not be NULL

ive tried to populate both the brand1_id and brand1_name fields with mappings of 2=brand1(Brand|id) and 2=brand1(Brand|name) with the respective entries correct in the csv, but no joy.

anyone else got past this?